# Constructor calling inherited constructor in java

Tags: java, class, inheritance, constructor, super

How would I go about doing this in java?

I need the constructor in my subclass to call the inherited constructor in my superclass. is there a special syntax that i need to use in order to do this?

I've used extends to inherit from the Person class. How would i go about using super()?

Here is my class:

```
public class Student extends Person
{
   protected int id;

   public Student()
   {
   // how do i call the inherited constructor here?
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`super(arg1, arg2, etc);`

There's an implicit call to `super()` (with no arguments) at the beginning of any constructor that doesn't call it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like that: `super()`. But I assume you need to call a method with arguments since there's an implicit call to `super()`. Add arguments, like this: `super(arg0, arg1, arg2, etc);`.